# Django Extend AbstractUser and use email Field as default in other field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django 1.9.2 with python 2.7.3, rest framework and allauth. I'm extending from django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and I want to get the email field from AbstractUser and use it as default in other field:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    email_from_work = models.EmailField(default=get_email())
```

But when I use this code, I get the following error:

```
File "./behnowapp/models.py", line 48, in MyUser
    email_from_work = models.EmailField(default=get_email())
TypeError: get_email() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What is the way for get the email attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to RA123 for the orientation, I have also overwritten the save method of MyUser and instead of implementing my own UserManager, I have implemented the default and I have added the necessary fields:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.email_from_work:
            self.email_from_work = self.get_email()
        super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=now)
    email_from_work = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Comment: The code section of `validators.RegexValidator` allow create a username with characters such as `.`, `ñ` or  `-` and `_` ?

Comment: It allows only to create a username with ".", "-", "_". You can test the Regex Expressions online with https://regex101.com/ and check if it matches the expression

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend `AbstractUser` for this purpose. Extend `AbstractBaseUser` for this. Inherit `PermissionsMixin`, if you want to use those features. And also make a custom manager extending `BaseUserManager`.

Example -

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)


objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # Fields necessary for making a user

def get_email(self):
    return self.email
```